# Scheduled tasks from remote server using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, system-administration

Please how to get Scheduled tasks and how to enable them from remote server using powershell

Comment: You can do this with schtasks. Syntax is here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766266.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Task Scheduler Scripting Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
$ComputerName = 'remotemachine.domain.tld'
$TaskName     = 'Name of disabled task'

$TaskScheduler = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service
$TaskScheduler.Connect($ComputerName)

$ScheduledTask = TaskScheduler.GetFolder('\').GetTask($TaskName)
$ScheduledTask.Enabled = $True
```